# find next element and remove class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove a class on a link within a span (span class="vote-btns") when the user selects an option from a select box (select class="songSelection_input")

```
<div class="jquery-selectbox jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced" style="width: 545px;">
    <div class="jquery-selectbox-moreButton"></div>

    <div class="jquery-selectbox-list jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced-list" style="width: 540px; height: 7em; display: none;">
        <span class="jquery-selectbox-item value- item-0">PICK YOUR FAVORITE MOMENT...</span>
        <span class="jquery-selectbox-item value-VoiceAngelFromMontgomery item-1">Angel From Montgomery</span>
        <span class="jquery-selectbox-item value-VoiceWhenWillIBeLoved item-2">When Will I Be Loved</span>
    </div>

    <span class="jquery-selectbox-currentItem">When Will I Be Loved</span>

    <select name="songSelection_amclaughlin" class="songSelection_input" id="select-amclaughlin" style="display: none;">
        <option value="">PICK YOUR FAVORITE MOMENT...</option>
        <option value="VoiceAngelFromMontgomery">Angel From Montgomery</option>
        <option value="VoiceWhenWillIBeLoved">When Will I Be Loved</option>
        <option value="VoiceTheClimb">The Climb</option>
        <option value="VoiceABrokenWing">A Broken Wing</option>
        <option value="VoiceAngelOfTheMorning">Angel Of The Morning</option>
        <option value="VoiceYouLie">You Lie</option>
    </select>
</div>

<span class="vote-btns">
  <a href="#" class="button fb grey">vote</a>
  <a href="#" class="button tw grey">vote</a>
</span>
```

I am trying to trigger this on change

```
$('.songSelection_input').change(function() {
  $(this).next('span.vote-btns').find('a.button').removeClass('grey');
});
```

I do not know how many spans are between the select box (it is dynamic) and vote-btns span, so I know why the next('span') is not working, but I thought specifying the next span.vote-btns would do the job, but it does not.

**UPDATED**: I should of included this as my html but did not, to simplify my problem. The siblings did fix my issue originally, but I realized the jquery selectbox plugin I use injects html (the span jquery selectbox items and hides the selectbox)

When I disable the selectbox jquery plugin, it works fine: http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/

http://jsfiddle.net/vkaCB/11/

Comment: I think you want to use .siblings("span")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse up the DOM one level, *then* find the siblings. The [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method can help. Try this:

```
$('.songSelection_input').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').siblings('span.vote-btns').find('a.button').removeClass('grey');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vkaCB/12/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.songSelection_input').change(function() {
  $(this).siblings('span.vote-btns').find('a.button').removeClass('grey');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/vWeLe/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, my fault for not including the real world html, I just included a simplified snippet of html thinking that would be comparable, could you have a look again?